# Maven plugin runs even if not declared in <plugins> section

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, parent-pom, maven-install-plugin

I have a parent pom and under `<pluginManagement>` I have a **maven-install-plugin** like so:

```
<artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>abc</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>com.abc.a</groupId>
                            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${basedir}/lib/test.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
   <plugins> <!--empty for demo purposes--> </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is one of my child projects' pom.xml:

```
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>child</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
     <plugins> <!--empty for demo purposes--> </plugins>
  </build>
```

I haven't defined the maven-install-plugin in the `<plugins>` section for both the parent and child projects but why is it still being executed when I run the pom.xml? And how can I prevent it from executing when I run my child pom.xml?

Comment: maven-install-plugin come with the maven binary distribution. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/. That means, even if you don't define these (core) plugins in your pom.xml, you can still use them. If you want to exclude install, then instead of `install` goal, you can use `verify` goal.

Comment: @Ramu No plugin is within the binary distribution of Maven (Download tar.gz/zip file and check the content https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) ...all plugins are being downloaded when needed...See the default binding for the plugins https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html

Comment: So can I prevent it from executing on my child modules?